# Python Debug Execution Mode

Tags: android, python

I've cross-compiled python 2.7.2 for Android (4.4.4) using the Android NDK 9d.

After loading the compiled items to the target I'm running into an issue where the executable works, but returns error code 1 for all actions except printing the version or help menu.

I copied the whole stuff to

```
/system/usr/bin/python2.7
/system/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
/system/usr/lib/python2.7/*

PYTHONHOME=/system/usr/
PATH=/system/usr/bin:/sbin:/vendor/bin:/system/sbin:/system/bin:/system/xbin
PYTHONPATH=/system/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload:/system/usr/lib/python2.7
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/vendor/lib:/system/lib:/system/usr/lib:/system/usr/lib:/system/usr/lib/python2.7:/system/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload
```

Is there a way to get python to be more verbose about why it returns an error code and refuses to work (like enter the interactive mode) so I can know if it's some sort of configuration issue or will I have to edit the code myself to figure out what is going on?

```
shell@devicex:/ # python2.7 --version
Python 2.7.2
shell@devicex:/ # python2.7 --help
usage: python2.7 [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Options and arguments (and corresponding environment variables):
-B     : don't write .py[co] files on import; also PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=x
-c cmd : program passed in as string (terminates option list)
-d     : debug output from parser; also PYTHONDEBUG=x
-E     : ignore PYTHON* environment variables (such as PYTHONPATH)
-h     : print this help message and exit (also --help)
-i     : inspect interactively after running script; forces a prompt even
         if stdin does not appear to be a terminal; also PYTHONINSPECT=x
-m mod : run library module as a script (terminates option list)
-O     : optimize generated bytecode slightly; also PYTHONOPTIMIZE=x
-OO    : remove doc-strings in addition to the -O optimizations
-Q arg : division options: -Qold (default), -Qwarn, -Qwarnall, -Qnew
-s     : don't add user site directory to sys.path; also PYTHONNOUSERSITE
-S     : don't imply 'import site' on initialization
-t     : issue warnings about inconsistent tab usage (-tt: issue errors)
-u     : unbuffered binary stdout and stderr; also PYTHONUNBUFFERED=x
         see man page for details on internal buffering relating to '-u'
-v     : verbose (trace import statements); also PYTHONVERBOSE=x
         can be supplied multiple times to increase verbosity
-V     : print the Python version number and exit (also --version)
-W arg : warning control; arg is action:message:category:module:lineno
         also PYTHONWARNINGS=arg
-x     : skip first line of source, allowing use of non-Unix forms of #!cmd
-3     : warn about Python 3.x incompatibilities that 2to3 cannot trivially fix
file   : program read from script file
-      : program read from stdin (default; interactive mode if a tty)
arg ...: arguments passed to program in sys.argv[1:]

Other environment variables:
PYTHONSTARTUP: file executed on interactive startup (no default)
PYTHONPATH   : ':'-separated list of directories prefixed to the
               default module search path.  The result is sys.path.
PYTHONHOME   : alternate <prefix> directory (or <prefix>:<exec_prefix>).
               The default module search path uses <prefix>/pythonX.X.
PYTHONCASEOK : ignore case in 'import' statements (Windows).
PYTHONIOENCODING: Encoding[:errors] used for stdin/stdout/stderr.
shell@devicex:/ #
shell@devicex:/ # python2.7; echo $?
1
shell@devicex:/ #
```

Thanks

Comment: WHere did you copy `PYTHONHOME` and the other env variables to?

Comment: They are exported on the shell before launching python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hacking in the code a bit, I realized that python requires the /system/usr/include/python2.7 folder contents to be present on the device. After copying that over, it now works without issue.

As for the original issue of not seeing any debug output, after looking more into the code, I also found that the stdout and stderr were redirected to sdcard log files so that's why I wasn't seeing the output of the error. After fixing that, everything is also fine on the output front.